# JavaScript Event Handling - Select not changing

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, event-handling, switch-statement, event-listener

I am attempting to use JavaScript to change the image that is displayed based on the option selected from a dropdown menu.

Using chrome monitorevents() I am able to tell that the change event is being triggered, however the variable direction is not being changed.

If I change the assigned value of direction manually, as you can see commented out, the correct image will display.

I'm sure it's something minor I'm overlooking, but I've been noodling at this pretty much all day.

I would appreciate anyone's input.

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <label for="choose-lighting" id="windowDirection">Which direction does your window face?</label>

        <select name="lighting" id="choose-lighting">
            <option value="empty">--- Direction ---</option>
            <option value="north">North</option>
            <option value="south">South</option>
            <option value="east">East</option>
            <option value="west">West</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="displayBox">
        <img src="" id="onDisplay">
    </div>

    <script>
        // var direction = document.querySelector("select");
        // var onDisplay = document.getElementById("onDisplay")
        var select = document.getElementById("choose-lighting");
        var direction = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
        console.log(direction);
        // var direction = "south";

        function chooseLighting() {

            // switch (direction) {
            //     case "north":
            //         document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_north.jpg";
            //         break;
            //     case "south":
            //         document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_south.jpg";
            //         break;
            //     case "east":
            //         document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_east.jpg";
            //         break;
            //     case "west":
            //         document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_west.jpg";
            //         break;
            //     default:
            //         document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_genericweb.jpg";
            //         break;
            // }

            if(direction == "North") {
                document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_north.jpg";
            }

            else if(direction == "South") {
                document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_south.jpg";
            }

            else if(direction == "East") {
                document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_east.jpg";
            }

            else if(direction == "West") {
                document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_west.jpg";
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById("onDisplay").src = "images/lightguide_genericweb.jpg";
            }

        }

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("load", chooseLighting, false);
        }

        else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent("onload", chooseLighting);
        }

        if (document.getElementById("choose-lighting").addEventListener) {
            document.getElementById("choose-lighting").addEventListener("change", chooseLighting, false);
            console.log(direction);
        }

        else if (document.getElementById("choose-lighting").attachEvent) {
            document.getElementById("choose-lighting").attachEvent("onchange", chooseLighting);
            console.log(direction);
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding (the setting of `a` to be equal to `b`) of `direction` only occurs once: at the very start. You should instead access the option every time the event fires: inside the event-handler.

You should also use `.value` on the select, as opposed to `options[index].text`. This will give you the `empty`, `north`, `south` values that you entered in the options' `value` attributes instead of the string values, which may not be optimal for use in code. By using the `value` attributes, you can substitute them directly into your image paths.

With both of these optimizations, you could simplify your code down to the following:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#choose-lighting');
// const onDisplay = document.querySelector('#on-display');

const chooseLighting = () => {
    const direction = select.value;
    
    let path;
    if (direction == 'empty')
        path = 'images/lightguide_genericweb.jpg';
    else
        path = `images/lightguide_${direction}.jpg`;

    // onDisplay.src = path;
    console.log('Set the image src to', path);
}

select.addEventListener('change', chooseLighting, false);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', chooseLighting, false);
```

```html
<label for="choose-lighting">Which direction does your window face?</label>

<select name="lighting" id="choose-lighting">
    <option value="empty">--- Direction ---</option>
    <option value="north">North</option>
    <option value="south">South</option>
    <option value="east">East</option>
    <option value="west">West</option>
</select>
```

You could even make the function a one-liner if you really wanted to, but that's probably not the most readable.

```js
const chooseLighting = () => onDisplay.src = `images/lightguide_${select.value == 'empty' ? 'genericweb' : select.value}.jpg`;
```

---

**Edit**: Following your question in the comment, here is the same thing implemented using more... traditional JavaScript.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#choose-lighting');

function chooseLighting() {
    var direction = select.value;
    
    if (direction == 'empty') {
        var path = 'images/lightguide_genericweb.jpg';
    } else {
        var path = `images/lightguide_${direction}.jpg`;
    }

    console.log('Set the image src to', path);
}

select.addEventListener('change', chooseLighting, false);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', chooseLighting, false);
```

```html
<label for="choose-lighting">Which direction does your window face?</label>

<select name="lighting" id="choose-lighting">
    <option value="empty">--- Direction ---</option>
    <option value="north">North</option>
    <option value="south">South</option>
    <option value="east">East</option>
    <option value="west">West</option>
</select>
```

I've even thrown in an intentional example of `var` being weird. You can see that, because `var` has function scope, I am able to perform `path`'s declaration *inside* the `if` statement. In any other language, that would make `path` only valid until the end of that `if` or `else`'s block. But not `var`: this oddness is part of why `let` and `const` have replaced `var`. The two new keywords behave as they would in any other language.

Comment: I am still pretty new at JavaScipt, but I see constants used quite a bit.  Is there a reason to use a constant and an anonymous function rather than a named function?  And a constant rather than a variable for select?

Comment: @green_bean `var` was "replaced" by `let` and `const` in 2015 with ES6. See [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/) for an overview of the differences. In this code, you could replace all instances of `const` with `var` and it would not change anything. It's a good habit to use `const` over `let` whenever possible because it helps avoid bugs (makes it so you can't re-assign a variable by accident), as well as communicates to others what your intentions are.

Comment: @green_bean There is no anonymous function in this code. I've just opted to use an arrow function instead of a traditional one. Again, in this case, there is no difference: you could replace `const chooseLighting = () => {` with `function chooseLighting() {` with no changes to the functionality of the code. While `var` has been "deprecated", `function` has not: my reasoning for using `=>` is nothing more than personal preference . You can find an overview of `=>` vs. `function` in [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/).

Comment: @green_bean I've added another snippet to the answer in an edit.

Comment: The explanation and comparison code is super appreciated.  Now I can compare them side by side and understand it better.  I'm sure in my course we will learn the more appropriate way of doing things, but one always has to build a solid foundation first. :)

Comment: @green_bean I'm glad to have helped  If this answer solved your question, don't forget to mark it as resolved by clicking the checkmark button under the votes counter. I wish you good luck in your course 